# Somar e total sql

Tags: sql

Olá tenho o seguinte sql: `SELECT sum(valor) as saidas,
(select sum(valor) FROM lancamentos WHERE id_tipo = 1 ) as receitas

FROM `lancamentos`

WHERE id_tipo = 2

group by id_tipo

`

Está funcionando ok, eu preciso que ele me traga a diferença entra receitas - saidas, numa coluna total.

ficando assim:

Entradas   | Saídas| Total
1.000      | -450  | 550,00

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Baseado na sua lógica, acho que isso resolve:

```
SELECT sum(valor) as saidas, 
(select sum(valor) FROM lancamentos WHERE id_tipo = 1 ) as receitas,
( ( sum(valor) as saidassoma ) - ( (select sum(valor) FROM lancamentos WHERE id_tipo = 1 ) as receitassoma ) as resultado
FROM lancamentos
WHERE id_tipo = 2
group by id_tipo
```

Mas, acho que com WHEN ficaria mais claro.

```
SELECT 
  SUM(CASE WHEN id_tipo = 1 THEN VALOR ELSE 0 END) AS RECEITAS,
  SUM(CASE WHEN id_tipo = 2 THEN VALOR ELSE 0 END) AS DESPESAS,
  SUM(CASE WHEN id_tipo = 1 THEN VALOR ELSE 0 END) - 
     SUM(CASE WHEN id_tipo = 2 THEN VALOR ELSE 0 END) AS RESULTADO
FROM LANCAMENTOS
GROUP BY id_tipo
```

Comment: Irei testar hoje a noite, muito obrigado pela resposta!!!

Comment: Consegui com a resposta do When do Valmor, muito obrigado! Me ajudou muito!

Answer (score 0):

Segue um exemplo prático

[Exemplo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f66bd7/2)

```
create table wp_grade(
id int primary key,
saidas decimal,
entradas decimal);

insert into wp_grade values(1, 30, 200);
insert into wp_grade values(2, 230, 150);

select 
sum(saidas) as saidas,
sum(entradas) as entradas,
(sum(entradas) - sum(saidas)) as EntradasMenosSaidas
from wp_grade
```